# Function to remove all classes on images inserted into posts?

Tags: images, media

I'd like my images to have no classes assigned to them by default, as I (sometimes) add my own classes to create custom 2 column layouts... can I do this without hacking the core?

From my googling it looks like image_send_to_editor would work, but creating a regex for this is beyond me...

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5129" alt="cl_1st_birthday_2" src="http://www.cyclelove.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/cl_1st_birthday_2.jpg" width="1152" height="768" />
```

to

```
<img class="" alt="cl_1st_birthday_2" src="http://www.cyclelove.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/cl_1st_birthday_2.jpg" width="1152" height="768" />
```

Comment: But the question is why do you want to do this? Why you want to remove these classes and add yours?

Comment: Could you please follow up on answers to your questions?

Comment: This was over a year ago! I'm sorry but I don't get notifications from this site so I didn't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner should do it, remove all classes.

```
add_filter( 'get_image_tag_class', '__return_empty_string' );
```

Filter can be found in [wp-includes/media.php](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-includes/media.php) in the `get_image_tag` function.

Comment: Where would one place this call? In one or all of the theme files? Somewhere else?